# Does a database table exist, using bash

Tags: sql, bash, ingres

How, in a bash script, could I tell whether an ingres database contains a particular table?

I think I want something like this:

```
sql $db << ENDSQL | grep 'TRUE' > /dev/null
select 'TRUE' from iitables where table_name like '$tablename%'
\p\g
ENDSQL
result=$?
```

but this is always returning `1` (not found).  A literal `'mytable%'` works, so I think it's something in my quoting (or lack of it).

The `\p` prints my SQL statement, and the $tablename is expanded even though it's inside the single quotes, so it's not that.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your script worked for me, providing db was set. However it always returned 0 because of the \p - you're printing out the query, which includes the string TRUE which you're grepping for.

Comment: @PaulM, but my problem is it's always returning 1, not 0.  Taking the \p out makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here document syntax is very picky, try a *here statement* instead (it's no less messy):

```
sql $db <<< "select 'TRUE' from iitables where table_name like '$tablename%'
\p\g" | grep 'TRUE' > /dev/null
result=$?
```

Note the <<< and the position of the double quotes.